# Gantry5 index.php jdoc:include

Tags: gantry

I'm trying to add this code:

```
$option = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('option'); 
$view  = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('view');
 if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'category') 
{
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="showcase" /> 
}
```

to my index.php (/rt_notio/index.php) of a Gantry 5 (Rockettheme Notio) template on a Joomla 3.10.12 / PHP 7.4.33 CMS.

But every time when I call the page I got a 404 error. Seems that the system doesn't render this code (especially the jdoc:include command) What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for answering!

Expectation:
Rendering the index.php to get my page online and inject the module "showcase" only on category pages, not on every article page.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="showcase" />` is not php code, so it has to be outside the php code delimiters.

The lines setting the `$option` and `$view` can be at the top of the file (within the php code section). The jdoc line should be within the part of the index.php file which has the html tags. Then you need to have:

```
<?php if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'category') : ?>
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="showcase" /> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

By the way, you may find the Joomla [Advanced Module Manager](https://regularlabs.com/advancedmodulemanager) extension gives you what you want without needing to override the template.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Robbie to answer my question! I'm aware of the Advanced Module Manager. Unfortunately this great piece of software gives me a lot of weird errors in conjunction with Gantr5/Rockettheme template/Joomla. My plan was to disable the AMM and implement such a piece of code to do the same.
Unfortunately I'm still struggling to get it to work. With the following code in my index.php I get a 500 error now:

```
> <?php
> 
> /**  * @package   Gantry 5 Theme  * @author    RocketTheme
> http://www.rockettheme.com  * @copyright Copyright (C) 2007 - 2021
> RocketTheme, LLC  * @license   GNU/GPLv2 and later  *  *
> http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html  */
> 
> defined('_JEXEC') or die;
> 
> use Gantry\Framework\Theme;
> 
> // Bootstrap Gantry framework or fail gracefully (inside included
> file). $className = __DIR__ . '/custom/includes/gantry.php'; if
> (!is_file($className)) {
>     $className = __DIR__ . '/includes/gantry.php'; } $gantry = include $className;
> 
> /** @var Theme $theme */ $theme = $gantry['theme'];
> 
> // All the custom twig variables can be defined in here: $context =
> array();
> 
> // Render the page. echo $theme->render('index.html.twig', $context);
> 
> 
$option = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('option');
$view = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('view');
<?php if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'category') : ?>    
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="showcase" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Your line `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="showcase" />` has to be within the `<html>` `<body>` section in index.php, not at the top. Like the other jdoc:include lines.

Comment: Sorry, there is no <html> <body> section in this index.php

Comment: ok, your theme must be implementing it a different way from the joomla templates. Is there another php file within your template area which has the `<jdoc:include>` tags? If so, you may be able to substitute your code in there. Otherwise I don't think I'll be able to help. You may be able to get an answer on the Gantry support forum

Comment: Allright Robbie. No, there is no another "known" php file which has the "normal" way to implement php code (like Joomla does). After read a lot it's obviously different with Gantry5. Will try to get an answer from this guys. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you get no answer there, then it's straightforward to write a system plugin which triggers on onRenderModule. In that plugin you can check for your conditions (option, view, etc) and remove the offending module. See https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Module#onRenderModule.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I think writing a plugin is beyond my IT skills. On the other hand, I'm surprised that this issue affects so many people and has not been solved yet: https://docs3.regularlabs.com/advancedtemplatemanager/going-further/not-compatible-with